# STM32+FreeRTOS issue when using “HAL_UART_TRANSMIT_IT”

Tags: embedded, stm32, uart, freertos

We want our device (STM32-F446RE running FreeRTOS + Telit ME310G1 modem) to communicate to the AWS cloud. We are trying to follow the Cellular Interface Library Demo, in particular following this- [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGse9.png)

We are using coreMQTT Agent, MbedTLS libraries, [the amazon communication interface implementation for UART](https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/feature/cellular/vendors/st/boards/stm32l475_discovery/ports/comm_if/comm_if_uart.c) and [amazon UART API implementation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/feature/cellular/vendors/st/boards/stm32l475_discovery/ports/common_io/iot_uart.c).

UART using 115200 baud rate.

Currently failing on the Cellular_Init function when trying to send the first AT command to the modem, specifically when calling the HAL_UART_TRANSMIT_IT function from the above comm interface send function. While debugging we see that the USART1_IRQHandler is called infinite times and nothing is sent through the UART communication.
We are using the default handler, do we need to implement it in any way?

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the UART line from HW point of view  are not in a good state (High).

Did you check and ensure that the Power On sequence is done correctly? (Power On telit pin shall be high).

I expect you have some logic to translate the 1.8v to 3.3v and vice versa.
Can you check by measuring the different voltage that everything is OK?

If you verified all the point above.

Do you perform a reset on the telit side  before starting the AT communication?
This ensure that you don't leave the module into a data mode where no AT commande are possible

Yacine